# Comparing dates with SharePoint PnP PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am wondering if should change my if statement that compares two dates if they are equal. Is there a better way of doing this operation? The code does what it supposed to do. No errors. The Code:

```
if((Get-date).ToString("yyy-MM-dd") -eq $ListItem["Aviseringsdatum"].ToLocalTime().ToString("yyy-MM-dd")){
Write-Output "True"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's okay, but we can do better. Let's see what `Get-Date` returns. Run this:

```
> get-date | get-member
```

It shows that `Get-Date` returns a `DateTime` object, and it also lists all the properties that has. I notice that `DateTime` has a `Date` property. Looking on the Web, it says that this is the date part of the `DateTime` but with a zero time component. So let's use that instead of converting to "yyy-MM-dd":

```
if((Get-date).Date -eq $ListItem["Aviseringsdatum"].Date){
Write-Output "True"
}
```

Since this is a code review, let's improve the formatting, and indent and add spaces:

```
if ((Get-Date).Date -eq $ListItem["Aviseringsdatum"].Date) {
    Write-Output "True"
}
```

I think that's as far as you need to go. If it were my code, however, I would probably go a bit further.

I would use `[DateTime]::Today` instead `(Get-Date).Date` because I think it is clearer.

I would also introduce local variables. I think if you are ever using a "today" or "now" value in your code, then it's better to capture them in a variable for the sake of consistency so that all parts of the script agree on what "today" or "now" is. What if for instance your script ran over midnight? Then the `(Get-Date).Date` value would suddenly change. A local variable might be overkill in this case, but it's a good practice in general to avoid some subtle bugs.

I also like making local variables to capture bigger expressions because they make for self-documenting code. It might be overkill again in this case, but I will add a `$notificationDate` variable.

```
$today = [DateTime]::Today
$notificationDate = $ListItem["Aviseringsdatum"].Date
if ($notificationDate -eq $today) {
    Write-Output "True"
}
```

I think that `$notificationDate -eq $today` makes the logic very clear to anyone reading the code.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I need. A Structrued way to improve my undestanding of well structured code. I tend to not break down the code into varibales. Thanks again!

Comment: Isn't there a presicision issue with equating dates? I seem to remember to have to use Get-Date and set the -Hour, -Minute and -Second parameters to zero.

Comment: @JohnDonnelly, that's why we use the `Date` property. Evaluate this in PowerShell: `(Get-Date).Date`, or `(Get-Date).Date.TimeOfDay`. You will see that the hours, minutes, etc. are zero.